# In IB how do I place existing components inside a new SplitView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder, view

I'm updating one of my Mac apps right now, and just discovered I need to place a SplitView behind all of my components. Is the only way to go about this the way I'm thinking? I need to move all components out of the current view and add a SplitView, then move everything back in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The components must be placed inside the split view. Using the document window in Interface Builder might alleviate some of the burden.

There’s a handy shortcut in Interface Builder for this operation: the Layout > Embed Objects In menu item. For instance, if you have two views and want to create an split view based on them, select them both and choose Layout > Embed Objects In > Split View.

Answer (score 1):

And in XCode 4.1: Editor > Embed In > Split View